# BackBone.js : "_ cannot be resolved"

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to retrieve list of object from Server and render it on html using Backbone.js
But facing "- cannot be resolved" error.

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-   bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page">

        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/template" id="product-list-template">
    <table class="table striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% _.each(products, function(product){ %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= product.get('category')%></td>
                    <td><%= product.get('description')%></td>
                </tr>
            <%}); %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </script>

        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"> </script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var Products = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            url: '/VeggieFresh/veggie/product/1' 
        });

        var ProductList = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '.page',
            render: function(){
                var that = this;
                var products = new Products();
                products.fetch({
                    success : function(products){
                        var template = _.template($('#product-list-template').html(), {products: products.models});
                        that.$el.html(template);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes : {
                '':'home'
            }
        });

        var productList = new ProductList();
        var router = new Router();
        router.on('route:home', function(){
            console.log('Backbone loaded.');
            productList.render();
        });

        Backbone.history.start();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Error is as follows:
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

```
An error occurred at line: 30 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
_ cannot be resolved
27:             </tr>
28:         </thead>
29:         <tbody>
30:             <% _.each(products, function(product){ %>
31:                 <tr>
32:                     <td><%= product.get('category')%></td>
33:                     <td><%= product.get('description')%></td>


An error occurred at line: 30 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
products cannot be resolved to a variable
27:             </tr>
28:         </thead>
29:         <tbody>
30:             <% _.each(products, function(product){ %>
31:                 <tr>
32:                     <td><%= product.get('category')%></td>
33:                     <td><%= product.get('description')%></td>
```

Any help/suggestion for this problem is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing Java and Javascript.  When you do something like:

```
<% _.each(products, function(product){ %>
```

in a JSP file, it gets treated as *Java* code.  However, the code you have inside the `<%` `%>` block:

```
_.each(products, function(product){
```

is *Javascript* code.

Since you can't combine the two different languages of Java and Javascript you get a Java error (the `JasperException`).